# What is the problem in the nodejs controller function?

Tags: javascript

```
exports.signupController = async (req, res) => { 
const { phone, password } = req.body;
try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ phone }).exec()
    if (user) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            errorMessage: 'Phone Number already exists',
        });
    }

    const newUser = new User();
    newUser.phone = phone;     
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    newUser.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    await newUser.save();    
    return res.status(200).json({
        successMessage: 'Registration success. Please login',
    });    
} catch (err) {
    console.log('signupController error: ', err);
    res.status(500).json({
        errorMessage: 'Server error',
    });
}};
```

**I upload a node application in shared hosting! **
*But an error was showing in this controller function. All the time the catch block is running on the json. The error is unhandled promise rejection. *

```
 signup(data)
   .then((response) => {
       console.log('Axios signup success: ', response);
       setFormData({
           phone: '',
           password: '',
           password2: '',
           loading: false,
           successMsg: response.data.successMessage,
       });
     history.push('/signin');
   })
   .catch((err) => {
       console.log('Axios signup error: ', err);
       setFormData({
           ...formData,
           loading: false,
           errorMsg: err.response.data.errorMessage,
       });
   });
```

this is react front end event handler

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const signup = async (data) => {
const config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
};

const response = await axios.post('/api/auth/signup', data, config);

return response;
```

};

the signup api function

Comment: I did it. Then the error is same. And the error shown as "uncaught promise couldn't read the data of understand difined"

Comment: You can also check for server logs to the error details. If you are hosting on Heroku, app logs are easily accessible

Comment: In the devwlopment server all is okay . It is actually in my vscode

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose queries are not promises. They have a .then() function for co and async/await as a convenience. If you need a fully-fledged promise, use the .exec() function. for example:

```
const query = Band.findOne({name: "Guns N' Roses"});
assert.ok(!(query instanceof Promise));

// A query is not a fully-fledged promise, but it does have a `.then()`.
query.then(function (doc) {
  // use doc
});

// `.exec()` gives you a fully-fledged promise
const promise = query.exec();
assert.ok(promise instanceof Promise);

promise.then(function (doc) {
  // use doc
});
```

If you are using exec() on your findOne query you should use:

```
exports.signupController = async (req, res) => { 
const { phone, password } = req.body;
try {
     const user = await User.findOne({ phone }).exec();
     /// just a pseudo code

     user.then('do your things').catch( 'log error')
  

    const newUser = new User();
    newUser.phone = phone;     
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    newUser.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    await newUser.save();    
    return res.status(200).json({
        successMessage: 'Registration success. Please login',
    });    
} catch (err) {
    console.log('signupController error: ', err);
    res.status(500).json({
        errorMessage: 'Server error',
    });
}};
```

for more details check this out: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#should-you-use-exec-with-await?